# Compiling Qt5 App on Raspberry

Tags: c++, qt5, raspberry-pi3, qapplication

I'd like to compile a program on my [Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/).

I've installed the latest [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and crosscompiled [Qt 5.8](https://www.qt.io/qt5-8/) as described in [this manual](http://www.tal.org/building_qt_5_for_raspberrypi_jessie) and then I've tried to build [GST](https://github.com/konsulko/headunit/tree/WIP/headunit-gst/gst) to run it on the board. The compile process seems to finish, however, I've got following linker errors:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/headunit-WIP-headunit-gst/gst# make
g++ -fPIC -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 libcrypto libusb-1.0 openssl` -I../jni -I/opt/Qt5.8/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.8/include -I/opt/Qt5.8/include/QtGui -c main.cc  -o main.o
g++ -o headunit ../jni/hu_aad.o ../jni/hu_aap.o ../jni/hu_ssl.o ../jni/hu_usb.o ../jni/hu_uti.o main.o `pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 libcrypto libusb-1.0 openssl` -L/opt/Qt5.8/include/QtCore/QtCore -L/opt/Qt5.8/include/QtWidgets/QtWidgets -L/opt/Qt5.8/include/QtGui/QtGui
main.o: In function `gst_loop(gst_app_t*, QApplication*)':
main.cc:(.text+0xb5c): undefined reference to `QApplication::exec()'
main.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0x10e0): undefined reference to `QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)'
main.cc:(.text+0x10f0): undefined reference to `qFlagLocation(char const*)'
main.cc:(.text+0x1104): undefined reference to `qFlagLocation(char const*)'
main.cc:(.text+0x1134): undefined reference to `QObject::connect(QObject const*, char const*, QObject const*, char const*, Qt::ConnectionType)'
main.cc:(.text+0x1140): undefined reference to `QMetaObject::Connection::~Connection()'
main.cc:(.text+0x1178): undefined reference to `QWidget::show()'
main.cc:(.text+0x11bc): undefined reference to `QWidget::winId() const'
main.cc:(.text+0x1280): undefined reference to `QWidget::hide()'
main.cc:(.text+0x12c4): undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
main.cc:(.text+0x12e4): undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
main.o: In function `QWidget::resize(int, int)':
main.cc:(.text._ZN7QWidget6resizeEii[_ZN7QWidget6resizeEii]+0x38): undefined reference to `QWidget::resize(QSize const&)'
main.o: In function `HuMainWindow::HuMainWindow()':
main.cc:(.text._ZN12HuMainWindowC2Ev[_ZN12HuMainWindowC5Ev]+0x38): undefined reference to `QMainWindow::QMainWindow(QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)'
main.o: In function `HuMainWindow::~HuMainWindow()':
main.cc:(.text._ZN12HuMainWindowD2Ev[_ZN12HuMainWindowD5Ev]+0x48): undefined reference to `QMainWindow::~QMainWindow()'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x8): undefined reference to `QMainWindow::metaObject() const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xc): undefined reference to `QMainWindow::qt_metacast(char const*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x10): undefined reference to `QMainWindow::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x1c): undefined reference to `QMainWindow::event(QEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x20): undefined reference to `QObject::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x24): undefined reference to `QObject::timerEvent(QTimerEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x28): undefined reference to `QObject::childEvent(QChildEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x2c): undefined reference to `QObject::customEvent(QEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x30): undefined reference to `QObject::connectNotify(QMetaMethod const&)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x34): undefined reference to `QObject::disconnectNotify(QMetaMethod const&)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x38): undefined reference to `QWidget::devType() const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x3c): undefined reference to `QWidget::setVisible(bool)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x40): undefined reference to `QWidget::sizeHint() const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x44): undefined reference to `QWidget::minimumSizeHint() const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x48): undefined reference to `QWidget::heightForWidth(int) const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x4c): undefined reference to `QWidget::hasHeightForWidth() const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x50): undefined reference to `QWidget::paintEngine() const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x5c): undefined reference to `QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x64): undefined reference to `QWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x68): undefined reference to `QWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x6c): undefined reference to `QWidget::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x70): undefined reference to `QWidget::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x74): undefined reference to `QWidget::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x78): undefined reference to `QWidget::enterEvent(QEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x7c): undefined reference to `QWidget::leaveEvent(QEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x80): undefined reference to `QWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x84): undefined reference to `QWidget::moveEvent(QMoveEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x88): undefined reference to `QWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x8c): undefined reference to `QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x90): undefined reference to `QMainWindow::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x94): undefined reference to `QWidget::tabletEvent(QTabletEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x98): undefined reference to `QWidget::actionEvent(QActionEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x9c): undefined reference to `QWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xa0): undefined reference to `QWidget::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xa4): undefined reference to `QWidget::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xa8): undefined reference to `QWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xac): undefined reference to `QWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xb0): undefined reference to `QWidget::hideEvent(QHideEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xb4): undefined reference to `QWidget::nativeEvent(QByteArray const&, void*, long*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xb8): undefined reference to `QWidget::changeEvent(QEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xbc): undefined reference to `QWidget::metric(QPaintDevice::PaintDeviceMetric) const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xc0): undefined reference to `QWidget::initPainter(QPainter*) const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xc4): undefined reference to `QWidget::redirected(QPoint*) const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xc8): undefined reference to `QWidget::sharedPainter() const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xcc): undefined reference to `QWidget::inputMethodEvent(QInputMethodEvent*)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xd0): undefined reference to `QWidget::inputMethodQuery(Qt::InputMethodQuery) const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xd4): undefined reference to `QWidget::focusNextPrevChild(bool)'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xd8): undefined reference to `QMainWindow::createPopupMenu()'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xec): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWidget::devType() const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xf0): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWidget::paintEngine() const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xf4): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWidget::metric(QPaintDevice::PaintDeviceMetric) const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xf8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWidget::initPainter(QPainter*) const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0xfc): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWidget::redirected(QPoint*) const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12HuMainWindow[_ZTV12HuMainWindow]+0x100): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWidget::sharedPainter() const'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI12HuMainWindow[_ZTI12HuMainWindow]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for QMainWindow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'headunit' failed
make: *** [headunit] Error 1
```

As far as I understand, there is no reference to [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#details), but I wrote it in the `Makefile`:

```
CC=gcc
CPP=g++
LD=ld
INCLUDES=`pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 libcrypto libusb-1.0 openssl` -I$(TOP)/jni -I/opt/Qt5.8/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.8/include -I/opt/Qt5.8/include/QtGui
CFLAGS=
CPPFLAGS=-fPIC -std=c++11
LFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 libcrypto libusb-1.0 openssl` -L/opt/Qt5.8/include/QtCore/QtCore -L/opt/Qt5.8/include/QtWidgets/QtWidgets -L/opt/Qt5.8/include/QtGui/QtGui
TOP = ..
AASRCS =    $(TOP)/jni/hu_aad.c \
        $(TOP)/jni/hu_aap.c \
            $(TOP)/jni/hu_ssl.c \
        $(TOP)/jni/hu_usb.c \
        $(TOP)/jni/hu_uti.c
HSRCS =     main.cc
OBJS = $(AASRCS:.c=.o) $(HSRCS:.cc=.o)
APP = headunit

.PHONY: depend clean

all: $(APP)

$(APP): $(OBJS)
    $(CPP) -o $(APP) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@

.cc.o:
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) *~ $(APP)

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $^

# DO NOT DELETE
```

I also tried qmake -project to get a project file and then qmake and make.
But then i receive other errors.

Maybe someone can help me fixing these problems to finally compile this program.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to let the Pi find the libraries by adding the /lib folder of the Qt installation to ld.so.conf?
In your case this would maybe look like `echo /opt/Qt5.8/lib | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/qt5pi.conf`

After that you have to reload the ld.so.conf by using `sudo ldconfig`

Now the linker can find the Qt-Libs without any additions to your Makefile.
Maybe this will help you.